# Launch laser_scan_matcher node

Tags: ros, laser-scan-matcher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I tried to launch the laser_scan_matcher package node. This is my launch file, but I can not see nothing on my rviz tool. Is something wrong with my launch file or just a rviz configuration?
The launch file is like this

```
<node name="rosplay" pkg="rosbag" type="play" args="/home/Daniel/Desktop/Data/test-41.bag           --clock"/>

<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="baselink_laser" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /base_link /laser 10"/>
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="laser_imu" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /laser /base_imu 10"/>
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="baselink_camera" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /base_link /camera 10"/>


<node pkg="laser_scan_matcher" type="laser_scan_matcher_node" 
    name="laser_scan_matcher_node" output="screen">
    <param name="use_alpha_beta" value="true"/>
    <param name="max_iterations" value="10"/>
</node>

<!-- Start an rviz node with a custom configuration for the viewpoint, map_server, trajectory, laser scans, etc -->
<node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" output="screen" name="rviz" args="-d $(find pow_analyzer)/launch/pow_rviz.vcg"/>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39436/launch-laser_scan_matcher-node/) by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2012-07-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2012-07-22**:
The bag file is 150 sec long. So have to add   this loop  . Wright? And the Rviz settings?I mean the target and fixed frame?

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2012-07-23**:
Any help on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`rosbag` is only going to play the data once. How long is that file?

If you want to play back the file repeatedly, add `--loop` to the `rosbag` arguments.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-07-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0